# How to save java source code in a .java file with the right name from terminal

Tags: java, node.js, ubuntu

I'm making a node js application running on ubuntu which receives some java source code, compiles and runs it and returns the output. I'm using the `child_process` module to execute commands like `javac` and `java` needed for compiling, etc and `fs.writeFile` to save the source code in a file. I'm very new to java and I realized that when the source code is saved as a .java file, it's name should be the same as the public class in the code or it will give an error when compiling. So what can I do to get the name of the class in order to create the .java file with the right name?

Comment: You can do a regex on the source to get the class name.

Comment: Would that be the right approach here? Don't get me wrong, I'm just new to java and not sure if there might be some weird situations where this wouldn't work.

Comment: well it depends. if there's no other way of getting the name apart from directly from the source then you'll have to manually extract it. and if there's only one class in the file then you can just get that class name.

if there's multiple classes in the same file then that could be tricker

Comment: Alright thanks. I was also worried about multiple classes being present but it looks like there can be only one public class per file.

Comment: Oh yeah you're right. So it'll be the only public class. Perfect! :D